# if __name__ == '__ STATIC main__' in tf2 tutorials

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [tf2 tutorial on static frames](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Adding%20a%20frame%20%28Python%29) abruptly ends without explaining this:

```
if __name__ == '__ STATIC main__':
    rospy.init_node('my_tf2_broadcaster')
```

I've never seen `__ STATIC main__` and from googling I can't tell if it's a ROS specific thing or general `python` syntax. I get no hits for it exactly, so I'm wondering if it's a typo. If so and it should be `'__main__'`, I'm still confused as it would appear the second block would never run.

Could someone clarify that section of code?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265532/if-__name__-==-%27__-static-main__%27-in-tf2-tutorials/) by [jwhendy](https://answers.ros.org/users/30308/jwhendy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2017-07-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-07-07**:
I'm not quite sure what this means; perhaps it is just supposed to indicate to readers that this is an alternate version for publishing a static transform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After going through the tutorials more, I agree with you @ahendrix. I submitted a [suggestion](https://github.com/ros/geometry2/issues/247) to just ditch the class-based static transform method for consistency/less confusion for beginners.

---

Originally posted by [jwhendy](https://answers.ros.org/users/30308/jwhendy/) with karma: 60 on 2017-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2019-01-19**:
[ros/geometry2#247](https://github.com/ros/geometry2/issues/247) should be in close-able state so this should be marked as an answer.

**Comment by [jwhendy](https://answers.ros.org/users/30308/jwhendy/) on 2019-01-19**:
I just closed that, and this is marked as an answer already.